# Joomla 2.5 ACL restrict to specific features/views

Tags: components, acl, joomla2.5

I seem to be having a problem identifying how to restrict Joomla 2.5 back-end users to specific features / Views in a custom component I am writing.  According to my understanding I should be able to add my views as a section in the access.xml file.  I have attempted this by naming a section the same name as my view but I don't seem to be able to change the access to that view independently from the component as a whole.  Does anybody have a more in depth example I can review or tips?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is not supported by Joomla.
My suggestion is to add a custom rule for views in access.xml

```
<section name="component">
   <action name="core.admin" title="JACTION_ADMIN" description="JACTION_ADMIN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
   <action name="core.manage" title="JACTION_MANAGE" description="JACTION_MANAGE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
   <action name="core.create" title="JACTION_CREATE" description="JACTION_CREATE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
   <action name="core.delete" title="JACTION_DELETE" description="JACTION_DELETE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
   <action name="core.edit" title="JACTION_EDIT" description="JACTION_EDIT_COMPONENT_DESC" />
   <action name="core.edit.state" title="JACTION_EDITSTATE" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_EDITSTATE_DESC" />
</section>

<section name="views">
   <action name="core.admin" title="JACTION_ADMIN" description="JACTION_ADMIN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
</section>
```

Then save your view in the `#__assets` table with a name like `com_component.view.playerlist`,
in the `rules` field you should save a JSON encoded list of your rules:

```
{"core.admin":{}}
```

You can check if current user can or cannot access a determinate section using `JAccess`

```
$user_id=JFactory::getUser()->id;
$has_permission = JAccess::check($user_id,'core.admin','com_component.view.playerlist');
if($has_permission){
    draw_view();
}else{
    JError::riseError(403,JText::_('PERMISSION_DENIED'));
    // or
    JError::raiseWarning(403,JText::_('PERMISSION_DENIED'));
}
```

If you have any doubt, feel free to comment.

Comment: I have a doubt! What is the relationship between the `<section name="views">` tag in the `access.xml` file and the `JAccess::check`?

Comment: And shouldn't the section be named "view" instead of "views"? I'm also studying about adding ACL to my extensions, but I'm not sure how the configuration is used by joomla.